# org.hibernate.HibernateException error in Eclipse, using Hibernate.!@!

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am making a simple hibernate program.
And I get this error.
I am using a Mac and Eclipse Framework for this.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at driver.main(driver.java:12)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
    at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:103)
    ... 5 more
```

From the driver.java , I wish to make changes to the Database using Hibernate. I am not aware of the errors.

I am using an object of the employee class in driver.java.

Here is the employee.java

```
public class employee
{   

private String name;

private int Eid;

private String city;

employee(){}


//getters
public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}
public int getEid()
{
    return this.Eid;
}
public String getCity()
{
    return this.city;
}


//setters
public void setEid(int a)
{
    this.Eid=a;
} 
public void setName(String s)
{
    this.name=s;
}
public void setCity(String s)
{
    this.city=s;
}
}
```

Driver .java

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class driver {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.configure("/Users/ronin/Desktop/Hibernate/employee.hbm.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory();
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    employee e = new employee();
    e.setEid(34);
    e.setName("Robin");
    e.setCity("Patiala");
    s.persist(e);
    tx.commit();
    s.close();
}
}
```

employee.hbm.xml file

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>


<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name = "employee" table = "employee">



      <id name = "id" type = "int" column = "id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>

      <property name = "name" column = "name" type = "string"/>
      <property name = "city" column = "city" type = "string"/>
      <property name = "Eid" column = "id" type = "int"/>

   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate, cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>   

<hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">admin</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 9.0.1

Comment: Great, just confirming that you're using Java9. I assume you've setted classpath correctly for the application and also have the `module-info.java` file at the root of your project, right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB is not readily available in JDK 9 as part of SE. I guess it is moved J2EE in version 9. Refer [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2016-May/004309.html)

To make the JAXB APIs available at runtime, you may add following command-line option

```
--add-modules java.xml.bind
```

or as a permanent solution you can use these dependencies by importing them using maven like,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: 
In case of  Java 6 use JAX-B Version 2.0.
In case of  Java 7 use JAX-B Version 2.2.3.
In case of  Java 8 use JAX-B Version 2.2.8

Comment: I am not sure how to do that in Eclipse!

Comment: I am using Java 9.0.1,which JAX-B version to use?

Comment: That Helped! Thanks!